# How do I comply with the CALM act in the US with loudness levels?

Tags: loudness, legal, legality, advertising

I'm a bit new to this, and I started working at a small TV station recently. I've read a little bit but I'm still confused. Does the CALM act passed in 2010 apply to commercials I make? How do I measure my ads and what maximum value can I hit? Should I get the other commercial producers to also comply, or does it not matter?

Comment: Besides my answer below, feel free to edit your question to narrow it if some points remain unclear after reading the A/85 document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not a lawyer, I believe that [the CALM act does apply to commercials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Advertisement_Loudness_Mitigation_Act), either the ones you produce in-house or the one provided by a third party (as I suppose you are in the US).

For the technical aspects of achieving such compliance, the [ATSC A/85:2013](https://www.atsc.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Techniques-for-establishing-and-maintaining-audio-loudness.pdf) seems a good starting point.